# How to rspec custom action with put in rails 3.1.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rspec2

We added a custom action approve in sourcing controller. Action approve updates the sourcing attributes. Here is how the approve is invoked:

```
<% link_to 'Approve', approve_project_sourcing_path(@project, src), :method => :put if need_approve?(src) %>
```

By specifying :method => :put, the attributes can be updated. Here is the rspec code for approve which failed:

```
it "should approve for vp_eng" do
  session[:vp_eng] = true
  session[:ceo] = false
  proj = Factory(:project)
  u = Factory(:user)
  session[:user_id] = u.id
  src= Factory(:sourcing, :input_by_id => u.id, :approved_by_vp_eng => false, :approved_by_ceo => false)
  put 'approve', :project_id => proj.id, :id => src.id, :sourcing => {:approved_by_vp_eng => true, :approve_vp_eng_id => session[:user_id],
                                                                      :approve_date_vp_eng => Time.now }
  src.reload.approve_vp_eng_id.should == session[:user_id]      
  response.should redirect_to project_sourcing_path(proj, src)      
end
```

The problem with the code above is that the src was not updated, even though in our execution test the attributes were updated as expected.

Our questions is that how to rspec the approve action with put? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

The rpsec for custom update action is exactly the same as rspec for RESTful update action. No :method => :put is needed.